# query-replace in keyboard macro

Tags: replace, keyboard-macros, recursive-edit

Let me define a keyboard-macro: I enter <kbd>C-x (</kbd>, then go to beginning with <kbd>M-<</kbd>, then type <kbd>M-%</kbd> to query-replace some occurrences of *foo* by *bar*. Out of 3 occurrences found, I replace only the last 2, then save with <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> and finish the kbd-macro with <kbd>C-x )</kbd>. Well done!!

If I now run the kbd-macro on another buffer, it will not ask me whether I want to replace *foo* by *bar*, it will reproduce exactly my previous no-yes-yes answers and replace the 2nd and 3rd occurrences! It will not ask for the 4th or 5th occurrences (this 2nd buffer contains more *foo*s)!! This is not what I expected when I defined the macro. I wanted it to call `query-replace` and let me answer its queries...

Aside question: Don't you find this wrong? [I can `M-x edit-last-kbd-macro` and see what is recorded and understand the logic of it all but I still find this wrong.]

Real question: What could I have used instead of `query-replace` to make my kbd-macro work as expected?

Comment: Personally, I don't find it wrong. The keyboard macro records *all* of your keystrokes—including the ones to specify the inputs for `M-%`—and plays them back exactly. I've never seen, and wouldn't expect, a macro that had interactive parts. You're probably better off writing a normal interactive elisp function at this point.

Comment: Simple. End your keyboard macro before you answer any of the queries. EDIT: I just tried it, maybe it is not that simple. I guess somebody could write a new command `start-kbd-macro-dwim`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emacs macros playback everything the user enters over the course of the macro, unless they escape the macro. The way to escape a macro in progress is with <kbd>C-x q</kbd> [`kbd-macro-query`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Query.html#Keyboard-Macro-Query).

Specifically I believe you need to enter recursive edit, which can prompt for a command in minibuffer before continuing the macro.

I think you want to define your `query-replace` when calling the macro.

- <kbd>F3</kbd> start the macro
- <kbd>M-<</kbd> jump to beginning
- <kbd>C-u C-x q</kbd> to enter a recursive edit
- <kbd>C-M-c</kbd> to exit recursive edit
- ... rest of macro actions
- <kbd>F4</kbd> to save, and repeat

On the next `kmacro-end-or-call-macro`, it will jump to the beginning of the buffer, and enter a recursive edit, where you can call `query-replace`. Then when you exit recursive edit <kbd>C-M-c</kbd> it will continue the macro from that point.

If you wish to prompt for an alternate argument to `query-replace`, it might make sense to write a simple interactive wrapper function around `query-replace` instead of using a recursive edit.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, this is recording everything *but* the call to `query-replace`.  It doesn't even seem like this will save the `FROM-STRING` or `TO-STRING`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was saying. If query-replace needs to be used interactively inside of the macro, without doing a replace all, I don't think a macro is appropriate

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem like a great fit for a keyboard macro, since you want to ask for user input.  Presumably you are wanting to record a macro because this is a `query-replace` that you intend to do frequently. If you can't make the keyboard macro do what you are after, you could create a keybinding to your specific call to `query-replace` as follows:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c q")   ;; Create a key binding for "Ctrl+c, q"
  (lambda () (interactive)      ;; Define an anonymous interactive funcion
  (query-replace "foo" "bar"    ;; Query-replace "foo" with "bar"
   nil                          ;; Don't require matching whole words
   1 (buffer-end 1))))          ;; Run from beginning to end of buffer
```

You can either add this to your init file and it will be available to you next time you start emacs, or you can take it for a test drive by pasting it into the `*scratch*` buffer and running `M-x eval-buffer`.  It is bound to `C-c q`, but that can easily be modified to whatever you want.